# Windows 7 Touch Events in Firefox 6 Browser

Tags: javascript, firefox, windows-7, touch, dom-events

I have written a small test page that detects and displays touch events using Javascript and HTML5 touch events. I want to test whether this actually works on a Windows Touch device. Unfortunately, I actually don’t have a touch enabled device so I’m using the Input Simulator that comes bundled with Surface 2.0 SDK to try to simulate these events. It doesn’t look like touch events are being raised in the browser (Firefox 6).

I have tried this using the TUIO plug-in by Fajran and using that to simulate touch events (so I know Firefox 6 definitely consumes these). So right now, I don’t know if these events are actually raised though in Windows 7 (I mean consumed by browsers to raise events).

Firefox said that it supported W7 Touch events in Firefox 4 onwards, but I have no idea if its still supported.

I’m still new so let me know if there’s something super obvious that I’ve missed or if there’s some more info I can provide. I looked through older posts and didn't see anything similar.

Comment: According to http://caniuse.com/#search=touch the touch events should be fully supported in Firefox 6.

Comment: I thought so too. However, touch events are not getting raised on a Windows 7 box on a touch. The same touch events are being raised with Safari Mobile (for example on my iPad). I can raise the events on Windows 7 using Firefox 6 (using TUIO for example). I used the Windows Touch Simulator to try to raise touch events also, but it doesn't look like its working with the w3c touch specs, but it does work with the API in Firefox 4. Would really appreciate knowing if someone has gotten it to work.

Answer (score 2):

This question has been answered here: http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/810808

*Firefox 6 for Windows 7 still uses the old "MozTouch" events, while Firefox 6 for Android uses the standard "touchstart"/"touchmove" events.*

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Good on you for answering your own question.